# Age is fraction of year man dies

Tags: arithmetic

My friend sent me a question from an olympiad and im not sure that we have followed the right method, we both did the same thing:

The age of a man was 2/61 of the year in which he died. How old would he have been if he
lived until 1992?

Surly then he dies in 1992 and then his age is 2/61 times 1992 rounded to the nearest integer? I am unsure though, this seems too simple.

Comment: It seems that you are right because there is no other info.

Comment: Which Olympiad!?

Comment: You're not reading it right.  It doesn't mean "how old was he, given that he died in 1992?"  It means "how old would he have been in 1992 (if he had lived that long, which he didn't)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let $a$ be the age of the man in the year in which he died and $d$ be the year of his death, then $a=\frac {2d}{61}$.

Since $61$ is prime and $a$ is an integer we have to have $d=61k$, in which case $a=2k$.

So if, for example, $k=32$ then $d=1952$ and $a=64$, which would give an age of [ ] in $1992$.

If $k=31$ then $d=1891$ and $a=62$ implying age [ ] in $1992$. To exclude this possibility (and others) you have to use a nonmathematical assumption, for example that human beings do not live beyond age $120$.

Comment: what is age []?

Comment: @simplton I left some work for you to do - if he was 64 in 1952, how old would he have been in 1992?

Comment: Why $a=\frac{2d}{61}$? Must be $a=\left[\frac{2d}{61}\right]$

Comment: Note also that we could try $k=33$ with $d=2013$ and $a=66$. So the date of the question could be material to the answer - if this were the solution,last year it wouldn't have been possible to say that he had died. However the wording "if he had lived ..." excludes this possibility - he clearly died before 1992.

Comment: and that would be 83, correct?

Comment: @GastónBurrull There is nothing in the question to suggest any rounding to the nearest integer, or taking the integer part, or anything like that. The fact that 61 is prime restricts the possible years to multiples of 61 - and 61 is a large enough number to make only one solution "realistic".

Comment: @simplton - how many years from 1952 to 1992?

Comment: 1992-1952+1, so its should be 64 +41 = 105?

Comment: I don't understand you, why is $d=61k$? This is an absurd since $d=1992$ and $1992$ is not divisible by $61$

Comment: @GastónBurrull But the man did not die in 1992 - he died some time before that, in an unknown year I called $d$. The information given in the question is not $d=1992$ but $d \lt 1992$.

Comment: @GastónBurrull The problem says that he was not alive in $1992$, so $d<1992$, not $d=1992$.

Comment: @simplton - If he had died in 1953, how old would he have been? You don't need an inclusive count here.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro If he lived until 1992 means that he dies in 1992. Right?

Comment: he would have been 64 giving 104 as his age in 1992

Comment: @GastónBurrull It says "if he had lived" as a counterfactual. Thus he did not live until 1992, and we are considering this idea as an alternative to the reality. Here $a$ represents the age he *actually lived to*, and [] is the age he *would have lived to* if he had not met his untimely demise in year $d$ and instead lived until 1992. (Note: "If he lived to 1992" and "If he had lived to 1992" mean two different things; this may be a grammar confusion.)

Comment: Oops, it doesn't actually say "if he had lived" in the OP. Well, it should have, since it does include the phrase "how old would he have been", which also indicates a counterfactual.

Comment: It doesn't say "how old would he have been in 1992?" but "how old would he have been if he lived until 1992?" Though this is a little ambiguous without the "had", there is a difference - the "if" suggest he "might have, but didn't". However he still couldn't have died in 1992, because the year of his death is specified to be divisible by 61.

Comment: I take the blame for introducing "had" in my comment - it isn't there. But I would still exclude date of death 2013, because the "if" suggests might have been alive in 1992, but wasn't.